# Which is more grammatically correct? "Did he suddenly go home?" or "Did he go home suddenly"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Did he suddenly go home?

OR

Did he go home suddenly?

Maybe it's more conversational to add the adverb "suddenly" at the last part of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and would be widely understood. The word order might also affect spoken emphasis or stresses, which might change how the sentence is perceived.

For example, if I wanted to emphasise the speed of his departure, I might choose this option and stress it as so:

> Did he *suddenly* go home?

Answer (score 2):

Intonation could change the meaning, but the questioner understands that he went home and is asking whether his departure was sudden:

> Did he go home suddenly?

Here, again, intonation could change the meaning, but the questioner understands that something sudden took place, and is wondering if his action was to "go home":

> Did he suddenly go home?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. There is no clear difference in meaning. Sometimes changing the word order changes emphasis, but I don't see any obvious difference in emphasis here.